# Select distinct with where clause and most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I need to find only the different ARM field values and STK respective, where DATE is the most recent and STK is greater than 1. 
That is, if the most recent negative I no longer want you to show.

The table is as follows:

```
Table MOV         

   Id       ARM   STK       DATE             
b3c842e3    F4    230   23-03-2019 00:00:00
b3c842e4    P8    832   24-03-2019 00:00:00
b32d4211    F4    -30   21-03-2019 00:00:00
6hhd421q    F4    100   26-03-2019 00:00:00
kih3221a    P8    -12   25-03-2019 00:00:00
```

The result I want is this:

```
ARM   STK
F4    100
```

I tried to use `SELECT DISTINCT` but I could not do what I wanted because of `WHERE`.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: And is that your starting point (all of your data) or your ending point (desired results)? Please show both, not just one or the other.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Comment: @AaronBertrand edited :)

Comment: Why is the second row not in your desired result?

Comment: @jarlh edited :)

Comment: @GenWan Because the 5th is the most recent and has the negative STK.

Comment: And what have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to assingn each row a number that is 1 for the largest `date` for all `arm` each and filter on that.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.arm,
       x.stk,
       x.date
       FROM (SELECT t.id,
                    t.arm,
                    t.stk,
                    t.date,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY arm
                                       ORDER BY date DESC)
                    FROM elbal t
                    WHERE t.stk > 1) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select top 1 arm, stk
from mov
where stk > 1
group by arm,STK
order by max(date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the most recent value with `stk > 1`:

```
select top (1) m.*
from mov m
where m.stk > 1
order by m.date desc;
```

Or, if you want rows where the most recent value for an `ARM` has `stk > 1`.  If this is what you want, then:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by arm order by date desc) as seqnum
      from mov m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1 and m.stk > 1
order by m.date desc;
```

Both of these return the one row you have specified.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ab5aa4b75fb18d01dbd1e0ccbf5129e) is a db<>fiddle showing that this does exactly what you specify in the question (well, it returns the full row, not just two columns).

Comment: I want all the different ARM values ​​that obey my where clauses. That is, that it is the most recent and that the most recent is not negative.

Comment: @BrunoGomes . . . Then the second is what you want.

Comment: No, because there is a more recent date (which is negative).

Comment: @BrunoGomes . . . This filters the rows so only the most recent row is taken, and then only when `stk` on that row is greater than 1.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I want.

Comment: @BrunoGomes . . . This is what you describe in the comments, in the question, and what the sample data returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this SQL to get your wanted result.

```
select t1.ARM,t1.STK from MOV t1
join (select Date=MAX(DATE) from MOV where STK > 1) T2 on t1.Date = T2.Date
```

but be aware, if multiple records have the same DATE, multiple lines would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by arm` to get all the max dates for each `arm`, then join to the table `mov` and reject all the rows for which the condition `stk > 1` does not apply.

```
select 
  m.arm, m.stk 
from mov m inner join (
  select arm, max(date) date
  from mov
  group by arm
) g on g.arm = m.arm and g.date = m.date
where m.stk > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3da0aad84dda0435d62f218d9493e7e2).
Results:

```
> arm | stk
> :-- | --:
> F4  | 100
```